# HG: How to push some (but not all) changes to 'stable' branch?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Say I do my new feature development either in **default**, or an entirely new branch made just for the feature for a web site project. When it comes time to push the feature out to the live website, I want to move it to the **live** branch, which I then `hg archive` to my apache directory.

Throughout everything, I want to be absolutely sure not to push other, unrelated changes that are not yet ready to be published to the **live** branch.

1. Is this even a good idea? Or should I be doing something entirely different?
2. If the code is in **default**, how do I push only the one thing I need and not everything to **live**? If I push just the latest changeset, is it smart enough to send the latest version of those files, or will it only do the changesets?
3. If the code is in an entirely new branch, do I merge the whole branch into **live**? How do I get those changes back to my **default** branch so I see them there too?
4. I was reading the "Task Based Management" section of the [Mercurial Kick Start](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/#merging-default-into-a-branch) guide and it mentions merging **default** into your branch. I found this very confusing and was wondering why you'd ever do this.

Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

[edit]
I'm using TortoiseHG BTW
[/edit]

Answer (score 3):

HG now has [Phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases). Change a phase of a changeset to secret and it will not be pushed when you use push. You can do it using TortoiseHG GUI.

In addition to that, be aware that just pushing or pulling something does not automatically change any files in the working directory. It only makes some additional changesets available. Only by using update do you actually change any files in your working dir. (unless you configure hg to update automatically).

In the example you linked, there is a bug fix in the default branch. Bob wants to have this fix in his branch too, so he merges default branch with his branch. This is just an example to see how branching works. You do not have to use it in exactly the same way. If you just begin your Mercurial adventure, then you should better use just one branch until you have a good reason to use more.

For example: 3 developers work on the same project and all of them use just one branch (default). 1 of the developers wants to do a major refactoring of the code. He wants to commit several very unstable changesets (many "in the middle of work"). Doing so in the default branch might upset other developers. That is a good reason to create a branch. After his version is stable enough he will merge his branch into default. While he is doing development in his branch, he wants to be up-to-date with other developers, so he frequently merges default into his branch. Staying in a separate branch for too long might result in difficult merges. Luckily merging is very quick in HG, so merge often.

Comment: I'm not sure Phases will work too well for this scenario. Keeping the branch to just one repo by not pushing it will not work for us because we do want other developers to have it, and we want it on our testing and staging servers. We just don't want it on our live server.

Comment: Hmmm. Then could you be a little more specific on what would you like to achieve? If you just do not want it on your live server, then do not push there.

Comment: I'd like to have a copy of the 'live' code kept within our main repo, so it's not just somewhere else that isn't linked. That way we can switch to it at any time to see exactly what changesets are out there. And we could do it from our development server. Plus, wouldn't it be hard to push only the bugfixes or other things we want to go out immediately if we didn't keep them in a separate branch?

Comment: Well in that case you can just follow the same pattern as Mercurial devs do when they work on Mercurial. Pull their code to see how it looks. Do development in default. Also have a "stable/live" branch. During normal development do not commit to stable. Commit to default only. If default becomes ready-to-release, then merge default into stable. I there is a need to do a quick bugfix in stable, then commit it directly to stable and also merge stable into default, so the fix is available in default too. I also find tags handy, I usually tag (label) specific changesets like 1.0, 1.1, etc.

Comment: When merging default into stable you do not need to merge the head (the latest changeset). For example let default contain 5 changesets: 1,2,3,4,5. You can update to stable and then right click on the chageset number 3 and choose "merge with local". Then you will only merge changesets 1,2,3 into stable.

Comment: The problem with doing all development working default, then pushing it out, is that we will probably never be at a point where EVERYTHING is ready to go live at once. We always have in-development changes that shouldn't be pushed. So for this, we still need a way to push these changes out w/o getting the stuff that's not ready yet - whether it's in a 'development' branch or 'default' or whatever...

Comment: Doing bugfixes (right in stable) then merging sounds good though; we'll do that for immediate changes.